# R dplyr change numeric values in sequence of rows to other numeric values

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following dataset. And, I want to change the range of values starting from `20010001-20010010` to `2001-2010`.

How can I do this?

Sample data (`df`):

```
structure(list(x = c(20010001, 20010001, 20010002, 20010002, 
20010003, 20010003, 20010004, 20010004, 20010005, 20010005, 20010006, 
20010006, 20010007, 20010007, 20010008, 20010008, 20010009, 20010009, 
20010010, 20010010, 20, 2, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14965, 14964
), y = c("2001", "ORIG", "2001", "ORIG", "2001", "ORIG", "2001", 
"ORIG", "2001", "ORIG", "2001", "ORIG", "2001", "ORIG", "2001", 
"ORIG", "2001", "ORIG", "2001", "ORIG", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2022", "2022")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -29L))
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

# To change a single value at a time
df["1", "x"] = 2010

# Now how to do it for a range of values wihtout having to do it one by one?
```

Comment: You mean 2001-2010?

Comment: How do your know 20010001 is 2011 and 20010010 is 2010? I mean, whats the criteria...

Comment: @LuccaNielsen, the whole purpose is to remove the three `0`s after `2001` in these sequence of values.

Comment: @PaulS, oh right thanks for point that out, silly me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution.

**EXPLANATION**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/imRhHu/1)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(z = str_replace(x, "2001[0]+(?=\\d{2}$)", "20")) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = T)

#>            x    y     z
#> 1   20010001 2001  2001
#> 2   20010001 ORIG  2001
#> 3   20010002 2001  2002
#> 4   20010002 ORIG  2002
#> 5   20010003 2001  2003
#> 6   20010003 ORIG  2003
#> 7   20010004 2001  2004
#> 8   20010004 ORIG  2004
#> 9   20010005 2001  2005
#> 10  20010005 ORIG  2005
#> 11  20010006 2001  2006
#> 12  20010006 ORIG  2006
#> 13  20010007 2001  2007
#> 14  20010007 ORIG  2007
#> 15  20010008 2001  2008
#> 16  20010008 ORIG  2008
#> 17  20010009 2001  2009
#> 18  20010009 ORIG  2009
#> 19 200100010 2001  2010
#> 20 200100010 ORIG  2010
#> 21        20 2020    20
#> 22         2 2020     2
#> 23        19 2020    19
#> 24        18 2020    18
#> 25        17 2020    17
#> 26        16 2020    16
#> 27        15 2020    15
#> 28     14965 2022 14965
#> 29     14964 2022 14964
```

Comment: Cheers, can you please add some explaination behind `"2001(0)+(?=\\d{2}$)"`?

Comment: I have just added the explanation to my answer, @Ed_Gravy,

Comment: In case you want to convert the new column to numeric, just use ` type.convert(as.is = T)`, as shown in my updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's more to it than this ...

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(x2 = if_else(between(x, 20010001, 20010010), x - 20008000, x))
#            x    y        x2
# 1   20010001 2001      2001
# 2   20010001 ORIG      2001
# 3   20010002 2001      2002
# 4   20010002 ORIG      2002
# 5   20010003 2001      2003
# 6   20010003 ORIG      2003
# 7   20010004 2001      2004
# 8   20010004 ORIG      2004
# 9   20010005 2001      2005
# 10  20010005 ORIG      2005
# 11  20010006 2001      2006
# 12  20010006 ORIG      2006
# 13  20010007 2001      2007
# 14  20010007 ORIG      2007
# 15  20010008 2001      2008
# 16  20010008 ORIG      2008
# 17  20010009 2001      2009
# 18  20010009 ORIG      2009
# 19 200100010 2001 200100010
# 20 200100010 ORIG 200100010
# 21        20 2020        20
# 22         2 2020         2
# 23        19 2020        19
# 24        18 2020        18
# 25        17 2020        17
# 26        16 2020        16
# 27        15 2020        15
# 28     14965 2022     14965
# 29     14964 2022     14964
```

Comment: Why isn't `200100010` changed to `2010`? Why do these two values stay the same? I really like your answer btw since it involves straight forward math.

Comment: Because you said `20010001`, not `200100010`. Am I supposed to infer? Also, you seem to be going with regex for other approaches, but your values are _number_, is there a reason for the inconsistency?

Comment: No worries, it's just that the data I have is messy, and I didn't make it, so I am just trying to modify it in a way that these numbers basically remain in 4 digits. Because, I am creating a `Shiny` app that loads the dataset and adds a new row to it with auto-generating the `x` value for that row. But, since I have these big `20010001`s inconsistent numbers, the app was adding `200100011` where it should have been `14966` (`after 14965`) in the new row for the year(`y`) `2022`.

Comment: I understand, user-provided or scraped data with somewhere doing auto-numbering can be problematic. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `stringr` package:

The feature or kind of funny thing here is to use all functions from the stringr package. `str_c` is equvalent to `paste0`, str_sub is quasi equivalent to `substr()` -> I find it easier to use in certain places like extracting the characters from last position. And thats it.
We extract the first letter in case x has more or equal to 8 characters and so we also extract the last 3 characters and paste them together. In case x has only for example 2 characters then x will be left:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(nchar(x) >= 8, str_c(str_sub(x, 1, 1), str_sub(x, - 3, - 1)), x))
```

```
       x    y
1   2001 2001
2   2001 ORIG
3   2002 2001
4   2002 ORIG
5   2003 2001
6   2003 ORIG
7   2004 2001
8   2004 ORIG
9   2005 2001
10  2005 ORIG
11  2006 2001
12  2006 ORIG
13  2007 2001
14  2007 ORIG
15  2008 2001
16  2008 ORIG
17  2009 2001
18  2009 ORIG
19  2010 2001
20  2010 ORIG
21    20 2020
22     2 2020
23    19 2020
24    18 2020
25    17 2020
26    16 2020
27    15 2020
28 14965 2022
29 14964 2022
```

Comment: Cheers, can you please add some explaination as to what `str_c(str_sub(x, 1, 1), str_sub(x, - 3, - 1)` this part is doing?